# Shell script for Oracle database dump

Tags: oracle, shell, sh

I'm trying to figure out how to do database dump for a specific schema in oracle. I came up with this shell script and I'm unsure of how to get this working. when i run the shell script i get the error saying

> The system cannot find the file specified.

below is the script I'm trying to run.

```
exp <username>/<passwd> owner=<schema>file=exp_<schema>_<date>.dmp log=exp_< schema>_<date>.log
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where have you placed your file file `exp_<schema>_<date>.dmp`?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? Can you post the entire command and error or are there any hints on which file cannot be found?

Comment: Is exp in the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out myself. I wasn't loading oracle home and library before running the exp utility.

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=`(set \`date\`; echo $2_$3)`

export LOG=/home/user/log
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/client/v11.2.0.3-64bit/client_1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin


exp < username > /< password >@//< host > owner= < schema > file=exp_$TODAY.dmp  log=exp_$TODAY.log

exit;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

you need  to create an oracle directory (and grant read and write to the appropriate users) pointing to an operating system directory then define the directory in the exp  parameter

create or replace directory DMP as 'C:\dmp'

grant write on DMP to user

exp / owner= directory=DMP file=exp_*.dmp log=exp*< schema>_.log